# Adding ngram to existing index

Tags: elasticsearch, n-gram

Is there a way to add ngram matching to existing index? I saw plenty examples in documentation how to create index which will search through using ngrams, but when I try to follow those instructions I get error:

```
{"error":"IndexAlreadyExistsException[[nameOfIndex] already exists]","status":400}
```

Example curl which I'm using:

```
curl -XPUT elasticUrl/nameOfIndex -d '{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
   },
   "mappings": {
      "title": {
         "properties": {
            "text_field": {
               "type": "string",
               "term_vector": "yes"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

Comment: Take a look here: https://gist.github.com/nicolashery/6317643. If a good remeber you are not able to change numer_of_shards when index has been already created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

First close the index, then apply updates and then open the index

```
POST /blog/_close
// apply index settings updates
POST /blog/_open
```

Source: [link](http://elasticsearch-cheatsheet.jolicode.com/)